# nginx and apache port number different but always showing apache2 page

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, xampp

i want to work with nginx and apache server both.
so i have installed nginx and followed all steps. i have set the port number 8000 to nginx.

but on this port, apache homepage loaded. even after stop the apache server.
i have uninstalled apache then tried. but still apache homepage showing.
i am using bitnami XAMPP, after i start XAMPP, generally it will start with dashboard,

> localhost/dashboard

but now, it's showing apache homepage. but XAMPP is running. how can i solve it.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

it is the result of

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1851/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1851/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6714/httpd
```

and

```
systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-07-19 02:41:23 +06; 42min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 1851 (nginx)
      Tasks: 9 (limit: 9385)
     Memory: 14.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─1851 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─6381 nginx: worker process
             ├─6382 nginx: worker process
             ├─6383 nginx: worker process
             ├─6384 nginx: worker process
             ├─6385 nginx: worker process
             ├─6386 nginx: worker process
             ├─6387 nginx: worker process
             └─6388 nginx: worker process

Jul 19 02:41:15 dip05-hp-laptop-15-da0022tx systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server>
Jul 19 02:41:23 dip05-hp-laptop-15-da0022tx systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server >
Jul 19 02:59:56 dip05-hp-laptop-15-da0022tx systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web serve>
Jul 19 02:59:56 dip05-hp-laptop-15-da0022tx systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server>
Jul 19 03:00:43 dip05-hp-laptop-15-da0022tx systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web serve>
lines 1-23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both NGINX and Apache share the same base docroot in a default setup of Ubuntu - `/var/www/html`.

Both are configured at the package level to **not replace the default docroot's index.htm(l) file if it is already present**.

Therefore, if Apache is installed first, the NGINX package will not replace the default docroot's index page, and if NGINX is installed first, Apache will not replace the NGINX landing page.

Check your configurations - and use different document roots.  Apache the config line is `DocumentRoot`, while for NGINX the config line is `root`.  Both sill have directory path arguments to the location where files and pages will be served out of.

But in a default install without configuraiton changes, they use the same docroot.